# Mutuable property passed from template is not updated

Tags: ember.js

I have a case where I am passing a property to child component wrapped inside a `mut` helper. Then I am updating this value in child component, and send action into parent component using closure action.

Then if I read this value in parent component with `get`, I get correct value. But if I pass this property to action from template, I get not updated value.

I've provided an [Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c0cf05f79cad3d2fa9fe8318e2ec0541?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C) to illustrate this problem (check out `console.log`).

Am I missing something in this solution? Or is it working as expected? Please take a look at `onInnerUp` action in `index` controller to see what I am trying to do.

I know this is very messy description, hope someone will understand what am I struggling with

Comment: Hm, what would you expect as behavior in the twiddle? I press the button and get the next number logged and shown in the template. Works for me.

Comment: You should see two values after click (first value is passed from template to action, second one is retrieved by using `get`). And they differ, but they probably shouldn't

Comment: Oh yeah. You call the action to early. You pass the value through the template, and the template is only updated on the end of the run loop. If you do it inside a `Ember.run.later` it will work.

Comment: Every binding in Ember is mutable, why are you using `mut`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as expected. Here is why?

When the template `index.hbs` is rendered at some point it creates an action via the action helper with the current value assigned to `controllerVal`. In your case; after the initial render that value is 0.

The action will only be recreated after the template is re-rendered. In your twiddle you are not waiting for the template to re-render and immediately triggering the action (which has already been created with the previous value of `controllerVal`). Even though the `controllerVal` is increased automatically (due to two-way-binding) when `value` within `my-component.js` is increased; the action is not yet re-created and holds the previous value; hence you get previus value that was assigned to `controllerVal` as parameter to your action. I hope I manage to explain what is going on in a simple way.

In fact Lux has already explained the way to overcome this situation in his comment above; but I have created a modified [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/622fc841195b96121bdac8b25b49ffc9?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C) for you. In this twiddle I am not immediately triggering the action; but delaying it till the next rendering is finished via `Ember.run.scheduleOnce(queue, target, method)`. I used `afterRender` queue in order to wait for rerendering of the template. You can look further for Ember run loop if you like. [This](http://www.programwitherik.com/why-you-should-care-about-the-ember-run-loop/) might be a good starting point I guess. My best regards.

Comment: I understand everything you say, thanks for good clarification